# Which set are these Mega Bloks pieces from?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification, clone-brands

Please help me identify which Mega Bloks set or sets these bricks are from.  Any help is appreciated.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Those look like Mega Blocks parts.

Comment: Appreciate your help!

Comment: The MEGA BLOKS logo on the parts seems to suggest that. ;)

Comment: Any1 has instructions for this set?

Answer (score 6):

These pieces are from Mega Bloks "Warriors: Future Force" set# 9528 "U-240 Assault".
(Instructions: https://support.megabrands.com/media/playbooks/9528.pdf)

[image]

Even though the picture is low resolution, you can see the orange parts on the three barrel turret better:
[image]

Comment: Any1 has instructions for this set?

Comment: Looks like the link is dead, see [here](https://yadi.sk/d/lCUUKCaee9eBF) for an archive containing (among others) the instructions for this model. (From Syberion's [answer](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/15627/3631) )

Comment: I have an unopened set with tape intact. I can see from the box cover those pieces are from Mega Bloks "Warriors: Future Force" set# 9528 "U-240 Assault"