# Please help identify this set & figures

Tags: part-identification, set-identification, minifigure-identification

Please help identify this set, and which sets these figures are from. Thanks!!

[image: ![enter image description here]

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Please consider selecting one answer from each of your questions as "correct" to give your questions closure. If more than one is eligible then select either the most useful of first posted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

1. [Set #8049 - Tractor with Log Loader.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8049-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)

[image]

2. ???
3. [Part # NBA005 - NBA Ray Allen, Milwaukee Bucks #34](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=18185#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D).

[image]

4. ???
5. [Part# NBA006 - NBA Pau Gasol, Memphis Grizzlies #16.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=nba006#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)
   [image]

Answer (score 4):

The "04" figure is from the set you asked about in another post ([Which set are these Mega Bloks pieces from?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/11578/which-set-are-these-mega-bloks-pieces-from)). It's from Mega Bloks "Warriors: Future Force" set# 9528 "U-240 Assault".

[image]
[image]

Comment: You are amazing!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

2. Looks like the [Islanders War-painted minifigure](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=pi070&name=Islander,%20Male&category=%5BPirates%5D%5BPirates%20I%5D%5BIslanders%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) head, but somehow mirrored from what is shown in Bricklink.

[image]

4. Is a clone-minifigure, not LEGO.

Comment: Also appears to be missing the white, opposite the red.

Comment: Yes, although that could be a photo-quality issue.