# Looking for instructions to Mega Bloks “Blok Bots” 9356 set

Tags: instructions, clone-brands

I need instructions for Mega Bloks "Blok Bots" set 9356.
Can't find it on https://support.megabrands.com/en-us/instructions

[image]

Comment: Looks like there is no hope of finding instructions there, since the theme you mentioned isn't on their theme list and their site seems pretty broken anyway (some of the themes on their list have broken HTML entities). Also, I heard Adobe Flash player has had its support dropped by Chrome (and possibly every other big tech company as well) so you should probably keep looking... I'm having trouble looking as well.

Comment: Hoping some1 will upload pics...

Comment: Hi igor and wlecome to Bricks.SE! You mention having searched on the brand website, but have you tried contacting their customer service department? They might be able to find the information you need. Additionally, by signaling the need for those files, they might put them up on their website for others to see. Don't forget to report here if you receive a reply from them!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this thread on Reddit:

(https://www.reddit.com/r/buildingblocks/comments/2t9xew/archive_of_old_mega_bloks_instructions/ )

It has a link to a zip file with instructions from the old mega bloks site.

It contains instructions for 9356 and 9528.